# Surrounding numbers in a table

Tags: tables, columns, framed

How to make two squares and two vertical lines as in the schematic?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx, makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools,float} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc, fit, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\allowdisplaybreaks[3]
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|cccc|}
\hline
\backslashbox{I5 I10}{Q1 Q0} &  00 & 01 & 11 & 10\\
\hline
00 &  0& 1 & 0 & 0 \\
01 &  0& 1 & 0 & 1\\
11 &  x& x & x & x\\
10 &  1& 0 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to surround the column as a whole, or each element individually?

Comment: @Bernard I want to surround the whole column

Comment: @Bernard The table structure has to keep the first cell diagonally because that is how the teacher usually represents the Karnaugh maps in Electronics.

Comment: Just add `($(pic cs:fromhere)+(0,.25)$)` instead of only `(pic cs:fromhere)`, as I've done in my second example.

Comment: See the edited version of my answer, I've used different colors and some dashed lines to differentiate the various types of sorrounding, but, of course, you can easily modify it as you prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow, float}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{postscript}
\begin{tabular}{|c|cccc|}
\hline
\backslashbox{I5 I10}{Q1 Q0} & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10\\
\hline
00 & 0& 0 & \Rnode{T}{1} & 0\\
01 & 0& 0 & 1 & 0\\
11 & x& x & x & x\\
10 & 0& 0 & \Rnode{B}{1} & 0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\ncbox[linejoin =1, nodesep=0.5ex, boxsize=0.25, linecolor=IndianRed]{T}{B}
\end{postscript}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first 1 appears to me without the complete rectangle. How can I fix this? I put the new code in the post and the image of the result you are giving me now.

Comment: That's a purely technical problem: to use `pstricks` code with `pdflatex`, you have to launch the compiler with the ` --enable-write18` switch if you're under MiKTeX, `-shell-escape` under TeX Live or MacTeX. This is because pdflatex has to outsource the making of the graphic to ghostscript (pdflatex has no computing engine for postscript instructions). Alternatively, you can compile with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 2):

With `tikz` you also can choose the shape of the surrounding border, here there are two examples with an `ellipse` and a `rectangle` with `rounded borders`.

I've also taken the liberty of suggesting an alternative way format your table.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc, fit, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|cccc|}
            \hline
            \backslashbox{I5 I10}{Q1 Q0} &  00 & 01 & 11 & 10\\
            \hline
            00 &  0& 0 & \tikzmark{fromhere}1 & 0\\
            01 &  0& 0 & 1 & 0\\
            11 &  x& x & x & x\\
            10 &  0& 0 & \tikzmark{tohere}1 & 0\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \node[ellipse, draw, blue, xshift=.27em, minimum width=1.5em,
                    fit={(pic cs:fromhere) (pic cs:tohere)}
                ] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{*5c}
             & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Q1 Q0}}\\
             \cline{2-5}
            \textbf{I5 I10} &  00 & 01 & 11 & 10\\
            \hline
            00 &  0& 0 & \tikzmark{fromhereii}1 & 0\\
            01 &  0& 0 & 1 & 0\\
            11 &  x& x & x & x\\
            10 &  0& 0 & \tikzmark{tohereii}1 & 0\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \node[rectangle, rounded corners, draw, blue, xshift=.27em, minimum width=1.5em,
            fit={($(pic cs:fromhereii)+(0,.25)$) (pic cs:tohereii)}
            ] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit: answer of the new version of the question*

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amstext} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx} 
\usepackage{siunitx, makecell} 
\usepackage{mathtools,float} 
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{float} 
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc, fit, positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} 
\usepackage{diagbox} 
\allowdisplaybreaks[3] 
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[H] 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|cccc|}
\hline
\backslashbox{I5 I10}{Q1 Q0} &  00 & 01 & 11 & 10\\
\hline
00 &  0& \tikzmark{c23}1 & 0 & 0 \\
01 &  0& \tikzmark{c33}1 & 0 & \tikzmark{c35}1\\
11 &  \tikzmark{c42}x& x & \tikzmark{c44}x & \tikzmark{c45}x\\
10 &  \tikzmark{c52}1& 0 & \tikzmark{c54}1 & \tikzmark{c55}1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
\node[rectangle, rounded corners, draw, blue, xshift=0.27em, minimum width=1.5em, fit={($(pic cs:c44)+(-.15,.25)$)($(pic cs:c55)+(.15,-.04)$)} ] {}; 
\node[ellipse, draw, green, xshift=0.27em, minimum width=1.5em, fit={($(pic cs:c23)+(0,0.2)$)(pic cs:c33)} ] {}; 
\node[ellipse, draw, green, xshift=0.27em, minimum width=1.5em, fit={($(pic cs:c35)+(0,0.2)$)(pic cs:c45)} ] {}; 
\draw[dashed, very thick, rounded corners, red]($(pic cs:c42)+(-.1,0.4)$) -- ($(pic cs:c42)+(.4,0.4)$) -- ($(pic cs:c52)+(.4,-.15)$) -- ($(pic cs:c52)+(-.1,-.15)$); 
\draw[dashed, very thick, rounded corners, red] ($(pic cs:c45)+(.4,0.4)$) -- ($(pic cs:c45)+(-.1,0.4)$) -- ($(pic cs:c55)+(-.1,-.15)$) -- ($(pic cs:c55)+(.4,-.15)$); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Second edit: `\tikzmark` explanation*

With the command `\tikzmark{<my_node_name>}` you create the node `<my_node_name>`, positioned where you write this command.

With `[overlay,remember picture]` you tell `tikz` that the picture you're creating has to be written where you have put the `\tikzmark`.

With `\node[rectangle, rounded corners, draw, blue, xshift=0.27em, minimum width=1.5em, fit={($(pic cs:c44)+(-.15,.25)$)($(pic cs:c55)+(.15,-.04)$)} ] {};` you draw a blue rectangle, with rounded corners, shifted horizontally by 0.27em, with a minimum width of 1.5em, which has to fit the points at:

1. the coordinate of node `c44` shifted horizontally by -.15cm and vertically by .25cm
2. the coordinate of node `c55` shifted horizontally by .15cm and vertically by -.04cm.

`\node[ellipse, draw, green, xshift=0.27em, minimum width=1.5em, fit={($(pic cs:c23)+(0,0.2)$)(pic cs:c33)} ] {};` draws a green ellipse, shifted horizontally by 0.27em, which fits the point at:

1. the coordinate of node `c23` shifted vertically by .2cm
2. the coordinate of node `c33`.

`\draw[dashed, very thick, rounded corners, red]($(pic cs:c42)+(-.1,0.4)$) -- ($(pic cs:c42)+(.4,0.4)$) -- ($(pic cs:c52)+(.4,-.15)$) -- ($(pic cs:c52)+(-.1,-.15)$);` draws a very thick red line, with rounded corners, which goes throught the points at:

1. the coordinate of node `c42` shifted horizontally by -.1cm and vertically by .4cm
2. the coordinate of node `c42` shifted horizontally by .4cm and vertically by .4cm
3. the coordinate of node `c52` shifted horizontally by .4cm and vertically by -.15cm
4. the coordinate of node `c52` shifted horizontally by -.1cm and vertically by -.15cm.

Comment: The first 1 appears to me without the complete rectangle. How can I fix this? I put the new code in the post and the image of the result you are giving me now.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Just write `($(pic cs:fromhere)+(0,.25)$)` as in my second example.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to make the same rectangle with the rounded corners horizontally how can I do it?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Of course you can! You've only to add other `\tikzmark`s and another node with the appropriate fitting.

Comment: But what command do I have to replace and which one do I have to use to make the rectangle horizontally just like you did vertically?

Comment: I'll put a new table and a drawing of mine with what I want circled in the post.

Comment: Thanks for help. I changed the post statement and I put a new code. I need two vertical lines and two squares in this new table, please.

Comment: Could you explain to me as if I had 5 years to do these surroundings please? I tried on my own but I can not get the same result, it's the first time I use tikzmark. Please.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález See the second edit of my answer, I hope it's clear...